# constructing sub class using super class instance

Tags: java, sockets

I have mysocket class which extends Socket  class..

```
class MySocket extends Socket {
    public int id;
}
```

now i have a subclass instance (Socket) which I got from accept method of ServerSocket.  How do I use this Socket instance to construct my MySockey instance?

Comment: Java != C++. Classes don't end in semi-colon.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you sure you really want a `Socket` subclass?

Comment: Why would you want to extend the Socket class ? Consider wrapping it instead. Read this: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh.html

Comment: if I extend Socket, I don't have to write wrapper for Socket methods in MySocket class..

Answer (score 1):

You get a `Socket` from somewhere so you'd better use a wrapper to add an `id` to it, something like:

```
public class SocketWrapper {
    private Socket socket;
    private int id;
    // getter, setter, ctors, ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the recommendation to wrap rather than extend Socket. However, if you decide to stay with extending, add a constructor to your subclass that takes a Socket as argument. Delegate Socket methods to it.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing a class makes sense only when you want to add some additional functionality to the class itself. In your case it seems you want to just use Sockets. So that the approach that @RC suggested is right. Rather than subclassing Socket class you can have a Socket object as an instance member and you can assign server.accept() return type to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know what you are saying is right.. But I need to know how to do this in subclassing way..

Comment: @suresh : since you are extending a Socket class, you can have a constructor in your class which will take some arguments and then from that constructor you can make a call to the super by passing some required/not required arguments.